# split an audio book mp3 (3.5 hours) into several CD sized mp3's

Tags: mp3, audiobook

I need to burn an mp3 onto separate discs because of it's size. Any applications out there that will do this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a tool like [mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html) to split up your audio file without transcoding. Doing it this way is faster than transcoding and preserves the audio quality.

[image: mp3DirectCut]

You can then burn the mp3 to a disc using [Windows Explorer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-in-Windows-Explorer), or a free third party tool like [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/).

Alternatively, if what you actually need is an *audio disc* that will play in normal CD players, [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) will burn multiple discs for you automatically. Just drop your audiobook into a new playlist. Right click the playlist and choose "Burn Playlist to Disc."

Answer (score 2):

I've always liked [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) as a free audio editing tool. While this might not be for everyone as you have to get the mp3 encoding library yourself, it is a very powerful tool.

Alternatively, you can go with the simple option, [MP3Split](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php). It is also free. Just give it a start and stop point and it will split the mp3.

As far as burning goes, [CDBXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) is a free burning tool that has always done me well.

Comment: FYI, `mp3splt` also [transcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding) .